# Surface, Metro, WinRT, MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, windows-8, windows-runtime

We are looking at creating a native client for the Surface (and similar) for our SaaS product. Is it straightforward to create a "Metro" app that can talk to a local instance of MongoDb on that device? I sort of get the distinction between WinRT (which I'm assuming we can't/won't support) and Win 8.x proper. I guess what I'm looking for is confirmation that a "hybrid" app is possible, and that it can be delivered in a reasonable fashion via the app store or similar. Hybrid as in a Windows Store type app, with the database being a mongo as a windows service.

Bonus question: What about Windows Phone (is it a completely different beast?)

I've read a fair amount of documentation but still can't fully grok all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deliver a native application via the Windows Store. Windows Store applications must use the WinRT ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj679957)). You'd need to find another (more traditional) mechanism for distributing your application.

What you're describing is just a Windows 32/64 application written in a variety of programming languages that has a style of a ["modern" application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh779072.aspx). The most common for Windows is very likely the [.NET MongoDB driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/). There is also a C++ driver that will work on Windows, but it's a **lot of effort** to get it to compile successfully (been there, tried it).

Further, be sure you understand the licensing for MongoDB before including MongoDB in the distribution of your application (it is [AGPL](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/103832439/the-agpl)).

Most importantly though, MongoDB is not designed or intended to be distributed to end users as it is a server product, not a product for workstations. It doesn't come with an installer, and is designed to be installed by administrators (as it would require port selection, path selection for the DB files, etc.).

I'm not sure why a SaaS application (which I'd think was a web site/cloud/style application that might have a locally installed application) would require a local database like MongoDB. I'd recommend you investigate DB options like SQL compact or Sqlite that could be fully embedded into an application without additional installations if possible.

Regarding your "bonus" question -- MongoDB can't be installed on a Windows Phone. I'd suggest just creating a REST API to wrap usage of MongoDB (or any other DB) and using that API to access a database.

Answer (score 1):

Metro style apps are designed for work on Windows 8 and Windows 8 RT, so I think requeriments are the same.

The problem is you will not be able to use  the Mongo Driver because it is not a PCL (Portable Class Library). If I'm not wrong the same is applicated for Windows Phone.

So you would have to develop your own PCL Driver or wait for one driver developed by MongoDB people.

**EDIT**

About @WiredPrairie's advice and MongoDB distribution, if you need a NoSQL database included with your application, you can try with [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). It has an Embedded version.

Comment: FYI: Licensing may be an issue with RavenDB as well: http://ravendb.net/docs/appendixes/licensing, unless you're prepared to pay.